# Probability: Terminology Question for Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

I'm currently probability from two different sources: the classic text by Billingsley and the course notes of an instructor at my university. I've run into a terminology conflict that I was hoping someone might clear up.

Let $F_1, F_2, ...$ be a sequence of distribution functions. According to Billingsley, $F_n$ is said to converge *weakly* to $F$ if (i) $F_n (x) \to F(x)$ for $x$ such that $F$ is continuous at $x$ and (ii) $F$ is also a distribution function.

Conversely, my notes say $F_n \to F$ *weakly* requires (i) but not (ii). If both (i) and (ii) are satisfied then we say $F_n \to F$ *completely*.

So, which is the more standard use? If I subscribe to Billingsley's definition, does complete convergence then have some different meaning [e.g. by strengthening (i)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my past experiences, I have used both completely and weakly to mean Billingsley's definition. But I understand where the professor is coming from, as it's nice to be able to distinguish between them.

So I thought I would check to see if this is true by looking briefly  through google. And what did I find? There are some places, like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution), that agree with my experiences. But there are many little papers, such as [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume11_2/514938.pdf), that agree with your professor. In fact, the only common thing I saw is that people always defined which one they used carefully, so that there was no confusion.

How like mathematicians to be exactly so! In terms of utility, I am now inclined to use the professor's definition. It's easier to be exact. But to answer your question, neither.

Comment: Well said. Amazingly (or perhaps not so amazingly if the use isn't standard) the paper you pulled up was authored by my professor. I like my professor's definition as well, but it makes studying both materials at the same time a little frustrating since the fact that they conflict alters the statements of several theorems, as well as their proofs.